# Calling from_buffer_copy in the constructor of inherited ctypes.Structure class

Tags: python, constructor, ctypes, init

I have the following piece of code:

```
class MyStruct(ctypes.Structure):
      _fields_= [('id', ctypes.uint),
                 ('perm', ctypes.uint)]
```

When the class is defined, i'm able to copy data from buffer directly on my fields. 
Eg:

```
ms = MyStruct.from_buffer_copy("\xAA\xAA\xAA\xAA\x11\x11\x11\x11")
print ms.id, ms.perm
```

Everythings works fine, here **id** will be *0xAAAAAAAA* and **perm** equals to *0x11111111*.

Now, i tried to do the same thing during the instantiation, with the following code:

```
class MyStruct(ctypes.Structure):
      _fields_= [('id', ctypes.uint),
                 ('perm', ctypes.uint)]
      def __init__(self):
          super(MyStruct, self).__init__()
          self.from_buffer_copy("\xAA\xAA\xAA\xAA\x11\x11\x11\x11")

ms = MyStruct()
print ms.id, ms.perm
```

But my code raises an error with the following statement :

> AttributeError: 'MyStruct' object has no attribute 'from_buffer_copy'

After some research i found that `from_buffer_copy` is a `ctypes._CData` method. On the documentation we can read that `_CData` class is [non-public class](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._CData).

So here my problem. I would like to use `from_buffer_copy` in the constructor but it looks 'not callable' at this moment. Could you help me ?

Thanks in advance for your reply
Regards

PS: I don't want to use the style `super(MyStruct,self).__init__(id=0x44444444,perm=0x11111111)` because on my real code there are a lot of arguments on my *fields* variable.

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but what about passing the values into the struct as a dictionary:  MyStruct(**fields) ? That solves the issue of having a large number of fields.

Comment: Hi Luke, the input data of MyStruct are not a list of argument (else, yes **fields could had been useful). Here i copy the exact same size of data in my field throught the help of from_buffer_copy.

Comment: Ok, then send the buffer to MyStruct, then in the initializer use struct.unpack to split into fields before calling super().__init__ ? Maybe that's a bit too awkward, plus wasteful since the data is just going to be repacked anyway.

Comment: My goal is to use from_buffer_copy for two reason. First, to avoid all extra stuff to parse. Because it's wasteful to split data(unpack, or others), and sort value per variable name (i will have to do it for all my structure). Next, i'm want to understand why we can call from_buffer_copy after the instantiation and not during. That's really a weird problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that from_buffer_copy creates *new* Structure instance from the given buffer. When you use it inside __init__, the Structure has already been created and thus there would be no way to make use of from_buffer_copy (and this is why it is only available as a class method, not an instance method).

An easy solution is just to keep using MyStruct.from_buffer_copy as you have or write another factory function to suit your needs. If you insist on using using MyStruct(buffer), then you can use __new__for this purpose since it is called *before* the instance has been created:

```
import ctypes
class MyStruct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_= [('id', ctypes.c_uint),('perm', ctypes.c_uint)]
    def __new__(cls, buf):
        return cls.from_buffer_copy(buf)

    def __init__(self, data):
        pass  ## data is already present in class

ms = MyStruct("\xAA\xAA\xAA\xAA\x11\x11\x11\x11")
print ms.id, ms.perm
```

Comment: It works like a charm. Thanks you very much for this pertinent answer!