# ctypes.Structure.from_buffer_copy doesn't check \0 for c_char-type

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I want to create `ctypes.Structure`-like object from `bytes` with `Object(bytes_buffer)`-like pattern.

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/11486058 I use `__new__` factory

```py
from ctypes import Structure, c_char, c_uint8

ARRAY_LENGTH = 5

class Person(Structure):
     _fields_ = [("name", c_char * ARRAY_LENGTH),
                 ("age", c_uint8)]
     def __new__(cls, buf):
        return cls.from_buffer_copy(buf)
```

When calling `Structure.from_buffer_copy` it looks like the method doesn't check the `\0` character (and it looks like Python-style)

```py
>>> p = Person.from_buffer_copy(b"Piter\x10")
>>> print(p.name, p.age)
... b'Piter' 16
```

But when calling `from_buffer_copy` from `Structure.__new__` the method checks `\0` character when interpreting `c_char * 5` (and it looks like C-style)

```
>>> p = Person(b"Piter\x10")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/denis/person.py", line 69, in <module>
    p = Person(b"Piter\x10")
ValueError: bytes too long (6, maximum length 5)
```

But using C-style string works well in both cases:

```py
ARRAY_LENGTH = 6

class Person(Structure):
     _fields_ = [("name", c_char * ARRAY_LENGTH),
                 ("age", c_uint8)]
     def __new__(cls, buf):
        return cls.from_buffer_copy(buf)
```

```py
>>> p = Person.from_buffer_copy(b"Piter\0\x10")
>>> print(p.name, p.age)
... b'Piter' 16
>>> p = Person(b"Piter\0\x10")
>>> print(p.name, p.age)
... b'Piter' 16
```

So

1. `Person.from_buffer_copy(b"Piter\x10")` interprets full array length when `\0` is not presented.
2. `Person(b"Piter\x10")` requires the `\0`.

I have no idea why it's so. Is it Python feature?

I run code with both Python 2 and Python 3

```
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 07:30:14) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
```

and

```
Python 2.7.18 (default, Aug  4 2020, 11:16:42) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux2
```

(used `"Piter\x10"` instead of `b"Piter\x10"`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've missed the empty `__init__`

```
from ctypes import Structure, c_char, c_uint8

ARRAY_LENGTH = 5

class Person(Structure):
     _fields_ = [("name", c_char * ARRAY_LENGTH),
                 ("age", c_uint8)]
     def __new__(cls, buf):
        return cls.from_buffer_copy(buf)
     def __init__(*args):
        pass
p = Person(b"Piter\x10")
print(p.name)
```

works just fine

you can read more about [__new__ here](https://www.concentricsky.com/articles/detail/pythons-hidden-new)

Briefly explained, `__new__` gets called before `__init__` and does what you want it to do, but then `__init__` gets called anyway and it doesnt know how to use your input

Comment: Thanks. A bit magic but it works for me. Should I use something like ```def __init__(self, *args): super().__init__()``` in general case?

Comment: `super().__init__()` is used when you are doing interesting things with inheritance. if you want to make your own `__init__` but also call the `__init__` from an ancestor then you need `super().__init__()`. in this case you want the opposite, you want to REMOVE the `__init__` of the ancestor.